# what can I change here in line 6-10?

Tags: python

How can I change my code (line 6-10) to get false, false, true in termunal as it is in the task?
Typing what I have now i gets:"false, false, false".

```
  def is_board_full(board):
  """
  should return True if there are no more empty place on the board,
  otherwise should return False
  """
6  for x in board:
7    if board != ".":
8      return False 
9    else:
10      return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
  # run this file to test you have implemented correctly the function
  board_1 = [
    ["X", "O", "."],
    ["X", "O", "."],
    ["X", "X", "O"],
  ]
  print(is_board_full(board_1)) # should return False

  board_2 = [
    [".", "O", "O"],
    [".", "O", "X"],
    [".", "X", "X"],
  ]
  print(is_board_full(board_2)) # should return False

  board_3 = [
    ["O", "O", "X"],
    ["O", "X", "O"],
    ["O", "X", "X"],
  ]
  print(is_board_full(board_3)) # should return True##
```

Comment: Your board is a list of lists. You should turn it into a flattened list before testing each element.

Comment: Also, your whole function can be replaced with `board[0] == '.'`. Because you only go through the first element in the loop, then immediately return, based on a single comparison that in itself already yields True or False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is go through each row in the board and check if "." is in the row. Change lines 6-10 to this.

```
for row in board:
    if "." in row:
        return False 
return True
```

Comment: Shouldn't `return True` be outside of the outer loop?

Comment: Oops. wrong edit when posting. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your question is not fully described. I assume that the function `is_board_full` should return `False` if there is a field with a '.' on the board.

Then your current implementation has two problems:
1.)
The function `is_board_full` is passed a two-dimensional array. You run with the loop in line 6 however only over the first dimension. So in line 7 you check if an array is not equal to the char '.'. This can never be true.
To check if '.' is in the row, you should use `if "." in row:` in line 7.

2.)
The `else` block currently causes only a single comparison to take place and then either `True` or `False` is returned. However, you should only return `True` if there is no '.' in any of the rows. So remove the else block and indent the `return True` so that it would be executed after the loop. Only if the loop does not already return `False`, there is no '.' on the board. character.

Your code should then look like the one in [Emmanuel's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72026880/what-can-i-change-here-in-line-6-10/72027056#72027056) answer.